# XSL: Unable to populate a value to HTML based on a condition

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am having an issue with preparing a correct XSLT template to populate values to HTML. In my case I want to populate a value of column **Test2** when it was a validation type on it.

My XSL template part is:

```
<xsl:for-each select="CurrentFile/RejRow[Col/ValidationType='Task: Non-Numeric']">
<tr>
  <td>
     <span>
        <xsl:value-of select="Col/ColVal"/>
     </span>
  </td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

And XML is:

```
<CurrentFile>
    <RejRow>
        <Col>
            <ColName>Test1</ColName>
            <ColVal>TestVal1</ColVal>
        </Col>
        <Col>
            <ColName>Test2</ColName>
            <ColVal>TestVal2</ColVal>
            <ValidationType>Task: Non-Numeric</ValidationType>
        </Col>
    </RejRow>
</CurrentFile>
```

**Update**: My current answer doesn't work for the situation when I need to check for several columns with several validations and output only those which didn't pass it. Still need assistance.

This approach doesn't work for me:

```
<xsl:for-each select="RejRow[count(Col/ValidationType)!=0]">
<tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="Col[ColName='Test2']">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="Col[ValidationType='Task: Non-Numeric']">
        <td class="warningTd">
          <span class="warningRed">
            <xsl:value-of select="ColVal"/>
          </span>
        </td>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="Col[count(ValidationType)=0]">
      <td class="warningTd">
        <span class="normal">
          <xsl:value-of select="ColVal"/>
        </span>
      </td>
    </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Please don't ask question A and then make an edit that transforms it into question B, so one has to read your non-working answer to A in order to understand B... Just ask question B directly and remove your answer if it's not relevant to that question.

Comment: Also, your question is not clear. What happens for columns that have a validation type *other than* `'Task: Non-Numeric'`? What happens for `<RejRow>` that don't have any `<Col>` with `ColName='Test2'`?

Comment: Those columns should not be displayed if they don't meet the condition. RejRows which are not included should be not populated.

Comment: So the condition is "there must be a `<Col>` with `ColName='Test2'` **AND** a `<ValidationType>`"?

Comment: You have not answered the questions in my second comment above.

Comment: Yes, exactly this.

Comment: I mean the second comment. There are two questions there.

Comment: I also mean it, the condition you mentioned is appropriate. Basically I as filtering values by specific column names and validation types.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you only want to output a `<RejRow>` when it has both a `<ValidationType>` and a `<Col>` with `<ColName>` equal to `Test2`:

```
<xsl:template match="/CurrentFile">
  <table>
    <xsl:for-each select="RejRow[Col[ValidationType and ColName='Test2']]">
      <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="Col[ColName='Test2']">
          <td class="warningTd">
            <span>
              <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="ValidationType = 'Task: Non-Numeric'">warningRed</xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>normal</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:value-of select="ColVal" />
            </span>
          </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this will create multiple `<td>` if there is more than one `Col[ColName='Test2']`.

Output is:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td class="warningTd">
         <span class="warningRed">TestVal2</span>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```